# making DropdownButtonHideUnderline width fit

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a row containing text and DropdownButtonHideUnderline ... the dropdown is not fitting the width .. like this:

[image]

this is my code:

```
   Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.42,
                        child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0),
                            child: Text("الجنس"))),
                    Flexible(
                      child:  new DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                        child: new DropdownButton<String>(
                          value: _data.gender,
                          isDense: true,
                          onChanged: (String newValue) {
                            setState(() {
                              _data.gender = newValue;
                            });
                          },
                          items: genders.map((String value) {
                            return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: value,
                              child: new Text(value),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
```

how to make the dropdown stretch to the width?

Answer (score 1):

**DropdownButtonHideUnderline** takes the width and height of the parent so to set the width you can wrap it in **Container** like this:

```
             Flexible(
                      child:  Conatiner(
                        width = double.maxFinite,
                        child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                        child: new DropdownButton<String>(
                          value: _data.gender,
                          isDense: true,
                          onChanged: (String newValue) {
                            setState(() {
                              _data.gender = newValue;
                            });
```

you can set the width to **maxFinite** to capture the remaining area.
Hope it helped:)